# как я могу получить отступ данных в std::variant на этапе компиляции?

Tags: c++, библиотеки, c++20, метапрограммирование, std

как я могу получить отступ данных в std::variant на этапе компиляции? На g++12 x86-64 данные в std::variant хранятся в первом поле, и их отступ равен 0. Но, к сожалению, я не могу найти в документации гарантий на такое поведение. Получается что данный момент зависит от компилятора и платформы. Как получить разницу между адресом данных, лежащих в варианте, и адресом самого объекта варианта на этапе компиляции?

Comment: Вообще-то никаких гарантий на счет внутреннего устройства, насколько я помню, стандарт не дает.

Comment: А зачем вам нужна эта разница?

Comment: @wololo, я хочу хранить разные типы хуков в варианте, один из них хук для boost::Intrusive::list.

Comment: Пример бы набросали, как незнание отступа мешает хранению хуков в `std::variant`...